# How to get desired word in flutter

Tags: flutter

Let's say I have this String variable:

```
String addressLine = "Mumbai - Pune Expy, Gold Valley Sector D, Tungarli, Lonavla, Maharashtra 410403, India"
```

And I only want to show `Mumbai - Pune Expy, Gold Valley Sector D`.

How to achieve something like this, and if the address line were different too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [split()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-core/String/split.html) function from dart:

```
String addressLine = "Mumbai - Pune Expy, Gold Valley Sector D, Tungarli, Lonavla, Maharashtra 410403, India"
List<String> newList = addressLine.split(', ');
print(newList[0]);   // Will give "Mumbai - Pune Expy"
```